# AngularJS: get array value by field name

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

In my first angular app i have such data:

```
tree_rows = [{"level":1,"branch":{"Name":"USA","Area":9826675,"Population":318212000,"TimeZone":"UTC -5 to -10","children":[{"Name":"California","Area":423970,"Population":38340000,"TimeZone":"Pacific Time","children":[{"Name":"San Francisco","Area":231,"Population":837442,"TimeZone":"PST"},{"Name":"Los Angeles","Area":503,"Population":3904657,"TimeZone":"PST"}]},{"Name":"Illinois","Area":57914,"Population":12882135,"TimeZone":"Central Time Zone","children":[{"Name":"Chicago","Area":234,"Population":2695598,"TimeZone":"CST"}]}],"level":1,"expanded":true,"uid":"0.5810681234579533","Options":[]},"label":"USA","tree_icon":"icon-file glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file","visible":true},{"level":1,"branch":{"Name":"Texas","Area":268581,"Population":26448193,"TimeZone":"Mountain","level":1,"expanded":true,"uid":"0.8260199765209109","Options":[]},"label":"Texas","tree_icon":"icon-file glyphicon glyphicon-file fa fa-file","visible":true}]

colDefinitions = [{"field":"Area"},{"field":"Population"},{"field":"TimeZone"},{"field":"children"}]
```

and i try to view it via table-grid-view:

```
<tr ng-repeat=\"row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid\"
            ng-class=\"'level-' + {{ row.level }} + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')\" class=\"tree-grid-row\">
            <td class=\"text-primary\"><a ng-click=\"user_clicks_branch(row.branch)\"><i ng-class=\"row.tree_icon\"
                       ng-click=\"row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded\"
                       class=\"indented tree-icon\"></i>
                </a><span class=\"indented tree-label\" ng-click=\"user_clicks_branch(row.branch)\">
                  {{row.branch[expandingProperty]}}</span>
            </td>
            <td ng-repeat=\"col in colDefinitions\">{{row.branch[col.field]}}</td> - this line!!!
</tr>
```

and all is ok, just that i want to display not all data as: `<td ng-repeat=\"col in colDefinitions\">{{row.branch[col.field]}}</td>`  but for example `{{row.branch[Name]}} , {{row.branch[Population]}}` and there i didn't see any data. But why?

How to get data from my array via field?

ps: i use this: https://github.com/khan4019/tree-grid-directive/blob/master/README.md

Comment: please paste your code in http://plnkr.co/

Comment: It hard to guess as it could be a lot of things until you share your code anywhere. First of all, I will not recommend this tree directive as first thing to try for angular. there are tons of beginner tutorials online for angular. However, if you want to try this tree directive, go to this demo link: http://khan4019.github.io/tree-grid-directive/test/treeGrid.html get treeGridTest.js and treeGrid.html and other libraries and play with it...and then place your data in the code and go from there...

Comment: @KhanSharp my code is this directive... all this is based on your link

Comment: @KhanSharp how from this plugin display only specific fields?

Comment: by using the column definition

Comment: @KhanSharp example please, and how to change view template of this plugin to use only my columns like {{model.field}} ?

Comment: i mean something like {{row.branch[field_name]}}

Comment: i mean something like {{row.branch[field_name]}}, i could write something like: row.branch[colDefinitions[0].field - but it is bad idea

Answer (score 1):

Try {{row.branch["Name"]}} instead, quoting the field name